# top 3 ranks corresponding to every partition in 3 different columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

Following is my table in SQL Server

```
ID      NAME    SALARY
10      A       10
10      B       5
10      C       20
10      D       20
11      E       40
11      F       40
11      G       30
11      H       50
12      I       50
12      J       35
```

My objective is to add six other columns first_value,second_value,third_value, first_rank, second_rank, third_rank corresponding to each ID.
The output should look like as following:

```
ID  NAME    SALARY R1   R2    R3     R1_name    R2_name    R3_name
10  A       10     5    10    20     B          A          C
10  B       5      5    10    20     B          A          C
10  C       20     5    10    20     B          A          C
10  D       20     5    10    20     B          A          C
11  E       40     30   40    40     G          E          F
11  F       40     30   40    40     G          E          F
11  G       30     30   40    40     G          E          F
11  H       50     30   40    40     G          E          F
12  I       50     35   50    NULL   J          I          NULL
12  J       35     35   50    NULL   J          I          NULL
```

Following is the insert query:

```
CREATE TABLE EMP(ID NVARCHAR(10), NAME NVARCHAR(20), SALARY MONEY)

INSERT INTO EMP
VALUES
(10, 'A', 10),(11, 'E',40 ),(10,'B',5),(11,'F',40),(12,'I',50)
,(10,'C',20),(11,'G',30),(12,'J',35),(10,'D',20),(11,'H',50)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think you should hard-code these values into your table (because if, at any point, the values change, you will need to adjust the entire table). It's also technically replication of data, which you should try to avoid. Instead, I think you should create a view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite ugly but it works, you could try

```
DECLARE @EMP AS TABLE(ID NVARCHAR(10), NAME NVARCHAR(20), SALARY MONEY)

INSERT INTO @EMP
VALUES
(10, 'A', 10),(11, 'E',40 ),(10,'B',5),(11,'F',40),(12,'I',50)
,(10,'C',20),(11,'G',30),(12,'J',35),(10,'D',20),(11,'H',50)


;WITH temp AS
(
   SELECT e.* , row_number() over(partition by e.ID ORDER BY e.SALARY ASC) AS Rn
   FROM @EMP e
)
SELECT e.*, t1.SALARY AS R1, t1.Name AS R1_Name, t2.SALARY AS R2, t2.Name AS R2_Name, t3.SALARY AS R3, t3.Name AS R3_Name
FROM @EMP e
LEFT JOIN temp t1 ON e.ID = t1.ID AND t1.Rn  = 1
LEFT JOIN temp t2 ON e.ID = t2.ID AND t2.Rn  = 2
LEFT JOIN temp t3 ON e.ID = t3.ID AND t3.Rn  = 3
ORDER BY e.ID ASC
```

Demo link: [Rextester](http://rextester.com/VWP81494)

Answer (score 2):

```
;WITH TOUpdate AS
(
  SELECT ID,
         MAX(case when RN=1 THEN SALARY ELSE 0 END) AS R1,
         MAX(case when RN=2 THEN SALARY ELSE 0 END) AS R2,
         MAX(case when RN=3 THEN SALARY ELSE 0 END) AS R3,
         MAX(case when RN=1 THEN Name ELSE NULL END) AS R1_Name,
         MAX(case when RN=2 THEN Name ELSE NULL END) AS R2_Name,
         MAX(case when RN=3 THEN Name ELSE NULL END) AS R3_Name
  FROM(
        SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY SALARY) AS RN
        FROM @EMP
                  ) X
WHERE X.RN<4
GROUP BY ID
             )

SELECT *
FROM @EMP E
INNER JOIN TOUpdate U
ON E.ID=U.ID
```

Answer (score 1):

We can actually achieve your desired output by doing a single join to a CTE which ranks the salaries for each `ID`.

```
WITH cte1 AS (
    SELECT ID, NAME, SALARY,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY SALARY) rn
    FROM EMP
),
cte2 AS (
    SELECT
        ID,
        MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN SALARY END) AS R1,
        MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN SALARY END) AS R2,
        MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 3 THEN SALARY END) AS R3,
        MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN NAME END)   AS R1_name,
        MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN NAME END)   AS R2_name,
        MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 3 THEN NAME END)   AS R3_name
    FROM cte1
    GROUP BY ID
)
SELECT
    t1.ID,
    t1.NAME,
    t1.SALARY,
    t2.*
FROM EMP t1
INNER JOIN cte2 t2
    ON t1.ID = t2.ID
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Demo here:**

## Rextester